# google cloud messaging send server error

Tags: android, http, message, google-cloud-messaging

I tried to play around with the gcm demo but I had some troubles to figure out why my server can't send message. I used the project number as sender ID for the android app and the server generated API key for the server side. I see that the app has registered to the server but once I send one message, the server crashes and shows :

```
message HTTP Status Code: 401

com.google.android.gcm.server.InvalidRequestException: HTTP Status Code: 401
    com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Sender.java:177)
    com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.send(Sender.java:121)
    com.google.android.gcm.demo.server.SendAllMessagesServlet.doPost(SendAllMessagesServlet.java:82)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: can you show your implementation ?

Comment: I am using the demo app by Google. The one in sdk/extra/google/gcm/samples. I changed the Sender ID and URL for the gcm-demo-client at CommonUtilities.java and the key_API in gcm-demo-server/web-inf/classes/api.key I guess this app should work for everyone but I guess I am missing some steps here.